# How can i receive sms from india to Us twilio number

Tags: php, twilio

I am Sending sms to twilio  usa number from india but it is not delivered.Can you please tell me why my messages are not delivered.

Comment: show your code what you have tried?

Comment: show the twillio response, you are getting?

Comment: Hi, I am receiving sms from twilio number but when i send reply  to it ,it is not delivering, the twilio number i used is USA number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

India imposes a number of restrictions on sending text messages which Twilio has documented here: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134167-Limitations-sending-SMS-messages-to-Indian-mobile-devices

If you continue to have issues that aren't addressed in the link above, drop a line to help@twilio.com.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hii , Thanks for the reply. I am getting messages from twilio but when i reply back it is not delivering.
I need to send reply  to twilio sms  and based on that reply i need to add my code.

Comment: See item 2 in that link. "Due to the sender ID change, SMS recipients are unable to send a reply back to your Twilio phone number"